# Supabase signup() fails - signup not allowed

Tags: supabase

I am trying to signup a new user with email/password. I am on a free tier, and believe I have made the necessary settings.

The Flutter code is:

```
Supabase.instance.client.auth.signUp(
    email: 'abcde@gmail.com',
    password: 'password',
);
```

I get this error

```
Signups not allowed for this instance
```

what should I be checking/setting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is likely due to you not having signups enabled inside the Dashboard. You can visit https://app.supabase.com/project/_/settings/auth in order to enable signups.